# Ignore parameters on page tracking using angulartics

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angulartics

I'm using Ui-router and in severals $states I have a parameter as a Guid like the example bellow (":numeroSolicitacao"):

```
     .state('solicitacoes/aprovacoes', {
        url: '/solicitacoes/aprovacoes/:numeroSolicitacao',
        views: {
           'conteudo-view@': angularAMD.route({
              templateUrl: 'js/app/visoes/solicitacoes/aprovacoes/aprovacoes.html',
              controller: 'ctrlAprovacoes',
              controllerUrl: 'controles/solicitacoes/aprovacoes/ctrlAprovacoes'
           })
        }
     })
```

Is there a way for doing globally to remove all ":numeroSolicitacao" parameters from track event with angulartics ? Otherwise each hit on this $state will be a different page for Google Analytics

Note: I'm adding the "$analytics.pageTrack('/solicitacoes/aprovacoes');" in all controllers already, but as I said I need some globally implementation.